# Reindexing Zebra Because there are no results found in opac and intranet search in KOHA Integrated Library System

Tags: indexing, ubuntu-12.04

I have a freshly installed Koha 3.16 in a Debian Server. I already imported the MARC records into the catalog, but when I search it on Opac , there is no results found.

I read this link: [My Zebra Indexing won’t work! How do I fix it? (AKA: I search for stuff and nothing comes up! Help!)](http://koha-community.org/documentation/faq/)

I have tried to follow what has been said in this link. But unfortunately Im stuck with the third step.

```
export PERL5LIB=/usr/share/koha/lib
export KOHA_CONF=/usr/share/koha/koha-conf.xml
/usr/share/koha/bin/migration_tools/rebuild_zebra.pl -b -r -v -x
```

I run this commands, but still, no luck. I tried to rebuild zebra using the command:

```
sudo koha-rebuild-zebra -f -v  mylibrary
```

The result shows:

```
Zebra configuration information 
================================ 
Zebra biblio directory      = /var/lib/koha/mylibrary/biblios 
Zebra authorities directory = /var/lib/koha/mylibrary/authorities 
Koha directory              = /usr/share/koha/intranet/cgi-bin 
Lockfile                    = /var/lock/koha/mylibrary/rebuild/rebuild..LCK 
BIBLIONUMBER in :     999$c 
BIBLIOITEMNUMBER in : 999$d 
================================ 
skipping authorities 
==================== 
exporting biblio 
==================== 
Records exported: 7922 
==================== 
REINDEXING zebra 
==================== 
18:04:12-13/11 zebraidx(8862) [warn] zebra_lock_create fail              fname=/var/lock/koha/mylibrary/biblios/norm..LCK [No such file or directory] 
18:04:12-13/11 zebraidx(8862) [warn] zebra_lock_create fail fname=/var/lock/koha/mylibrary/biblios/shadow..LCK [No such file or directory] 
18:04:12-13/11 zebraidx(8862) [fatal] Could not select database biblios errCode=109 
18:04:12-13/11 zebraidx(8863) [warn] zebra_lock_create fail fname=/var/lock/koha/mylibrary/biblios/norm..LCK [No such file or directory] 
18:04:12-13/11 zebraidx(8863) [warn] zebra_lock_create fail fname=/var/lock/koha/mylibrary/biblios/shadow..LCK [No such file or directory] 
18:04:12-13/11 zebraidx(8863) [fatal] Could not select database biblios errCode=109 
==================== 
CLEANING 
==================== 
Zebra configuration information 
================================ 
Zebra biblio directory      = /var/lib/koha/mylibrary/biblios 
Zebra authorities directory = /var/lib/koha/mylibrary/authorities 
Koha directory              = /usr/share/koha/intranet/cgi-bin 
Lockfile                    = /var/lock/koha/mylibrary/rebuild/rebuild..LCK 
BIBLIONUMBER in :     999$c 
BIBLIOITEMNUMBER in : 999$d 
================================ 
==================== 
exporting authority 
==================== 

Records exported: 0 
==================== 
REINDEXING zebra 
==================== 
skipping biblios 
==================== 
CLEANING 
====================
```

Whats wrong with reindexing Zebra? How will I fix it? I found a problem same with me, but honestly I dont get how to apply a Patch.Here's the link:

[zebraidx errCode=109](http://koha.1045719.n5.nabble.com/zebraidx-errCode-109-td5720842.html#a5818701)

Please fix it. I really have to get this working.

Answer (score 3):

Happened the same when install koha in Centos. Try:

```
Koha-rebuild-zebra -f -v -b mylibrary
```

You can use these lines to restart the search tables.

```
sudo zebraidx -c /etc/koha/sites/library/zebra-biblios.cfg drop biblios
sudo zebraidx -c /etc/koha/sites/library/zebra-biblios.cfg commit 
koha-rebuild-zebra -b -r -v mylibrary
```

- Finally: Try to change the parameter SearchEngine in the preferences section. Zebra to Solr.

Other parameters ([source](https://wiki.koha-community.org/wiki/Commands_provided_by_the_Debian_packages#koha-rebuild-zebra)):

- `-f, --full` Does a reindex of the whole collection. Will run even if USE_INDEXER_DAEMON=yes.
- `-a, --authorities` Only run the indexing process for authority records.
- `-b, --biblios` Only run the indexing process for biblio records.
- `-q, --quiet` Sometimes be a bit quieter for scripts/cronjobs.
- `-v, --verbose` Be verbose. Useful for debugging indexing problems.

Comment: i love you <333

Answer (score 1):

Hi your all previous step looks great
after all the above steps as followed by user till `/usr/share/koha/bin/migration_tools/rebuild_zebra.pl -b -r -v -x` looks fine
after that you give the following command
`zebrasrv -f /path/to/the.KOHA_CONF` file i.e xml file which should run in background process else if you get logout indexing also go off

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, zebraserv seems to exit randomly. The log is not much help, as it does not capture what caused the crash.  The symptom is that searches don't work. I found that restarting koha fixes the issue. However restarting all the time is not ideal. Some investigation on my system ( Debian 8.3 with Koha 16.05.05.000 ) reveal that the zebraserv process dying is a symptom of the issue.  I wrote this script to be run as a cron job ( for root ) that runs every 60 seconds. This appears to make it recover. It seems to happen once every few days.

This has been happening in the last few releases of koha-common via Debian apt-get

I called it /root/check_zebra.sh  ..... it is

```
:
# Add this to cron i.e ( remove the leading "#" ) for root
# * * * * * /root/check_zebra.sh >> /root/check_zebra.log
#
ps ax | grep  zebrasrv | grep koha-conf.xml > /dev/null
status=$?
if [ $status = "0" ]
then
  :
else
  # Restart
  echo "============================================="
  date
  echo "zebrasrv has stopped. Restarting Koka..."
  echo "/etc/init.d/koha-common restart"
  /etc/init.d/koha-common restart
fi
```